# Can not estimate remaining battery time?

Tags: 10.10, battery, power-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Laptop's battery is stuck on “estimating”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7205/laptops-battery-is-stuck-on-estimating)

After updating to Ubuntu 10.10 from 10.04 Ubuntu can not estimate both the battery time and the percentage left. It just says (estimating...)