# Battery indicator is stuck on "estimating"?

Tags: 10.10, indicator, battery, acpi

After installing Ubuntu 10.10, the battery indicator worked fine (both percent remaining and estimation on time). I then installed and configured some software (Skype, Pidgin, Thunderbird, removed Empathy and Evolution, ect) and the battery meter, when clicked, always says "(estimating...)"

I've tried running the battery down to zero and charging it fully again. If I go into the history or details, the percentage is recorded correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Having same problem with my Lenovo N200 with 11.04. Going to try the applet.

Comment: try install/reinstall `gnome-power-manager`. maybe fixed

Comment: power IC or Charging IC must have Failed. Take it to a engineer to get it changed.

Comment: after 11 years, now I am facing this problem in 2022 with Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Same here with 22.04.2 LTS on HP ZBook Fury 17 G7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is known bug that affects HP, Compaq, Dell and other manufactures. This is because of a change made in gnome-power-manager where by the estimate is done on time remaining, rather than percentage. This change does not play nice with some hardware and is why you are seeing (estimaing...) constantly.

The bug report about it is here if you fancy a read:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/629258

At this time, I believe there is no fix available. However you can click on the estimating... and it will bring up a more detailed view of your battery info, which will display the percentage of charge.

Comment: But why did it work before?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you have one of the systems specified in the bug report, there's not much you can do at this time.

Comment: Correction, it's a bug in upower. A patch has been released to enable timed statistics to work under the affected laptops/netbooks

Answer (score 7):

[Battery Status](https://github.com/ia/battery-status) is a good alternative applet that will show the battery percentage.

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/battery-status-ppa-finally-updated-with.html

Run these two commands to install a ppa for the new indicator:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:iaz/battery-status && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install battery-status
```

Now start the new battery indicator (it will replace the default indicator for future logins):

```
nohup /usr/lib/battery-status/battery-status --indicator &
```

If this bug affects you, say so at the bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+source/upower/+bug/629258

Comment: I works great. And it should be the answer for the question.

Comment: first command is not working:   
`Ign:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/iaz/battery-status/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/iaz/battery-status/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]`

Answer (score 3):

Bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-release-notes/+bug/629258

Entry #91 fixed my x64 HP Pavilion:

> Steps to apply @Brian's PPA update:
>
> > 1) From a terminal window:
> >
> > > sudo add-apt-repository ppa:brian-rogers/power
> > >
> > > sudo apt-get update
> > >
> > > sudo apt-get upgrade
> >
> > 2) Reboot
> >
> > 3) Login normally, click on the battery icon

Comment: First command not working: `Err:11 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/brian-rogers/power/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Err:12 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/iaz/battery-status/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
`

Answer (score 0):

I experience this behaviour whenever I use a power adaptor that cannot supply the appropriate amount of power to the laptop, such as using a monitor adaptor for my laptop (I left mine at home that day). There's probably been an update to the kernel (most likely, but it could be something else) that's causing Ubuntu to not get the appropriate amount of charge out of the wall. Try booting up with the previous kernel version(s) and see what happens.

Comment: I'm using an original power adaptor so that is not the case for me, but I will try loading with a previous kernel. I am running an unstable one so that may be the reason...

Comment: You were right. When I use the kernel 35-22 Ubuntu can estimate the time left... Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, as far as i search there is not any way to solve this problem in unity panel but i solved it buy installing cairo-dock. It has some theme that can show percentages over its image.

You can install cairo-dock from repository

```
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock
```

then after running it:

1. in cairo-dock configuration go to add-ons tab.
2. tick "Power Manager" applet and click apply button.
3. in the dock right click on "Power Manager" applet and from "power manager" menu click on edit button.
4. in shown dialogue goto "Configuration" tab.
5. from first combo bos ("choose the style of disply") select "Gauge".
6. open Gauge section and from "choose one of the available theme" select a theme that show percentages in its image (theme like, "Battery-Mono" , "Battery:MeeGo theme" , "Battery:Oxygen theme" ,...)