# Workaround for misbehaving Battery Notifier (always estimating)

Tags: 10.10, battery, gnome-power-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Laptop's battery is stuck on “estimating”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7205/laptops-battery-is-stuck-on-estimating)

I know this is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upower/+bug/629258) which has been [asked before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7205/laptops-battery-is-stuck-on-estimating) but I hope that until now  there might be a fix or workaround to estimate the left battery.
The battery is stuck on **estimating** on Maverick, It was not an issue with Lucid.

[image: showing the estimating in the menu]