# Showing error on battery state

Tags: 10.10

I am a newbie to Linux and I am using Ubuntu 10.10 on one of my systems. When I am trying to open it, it is showing something like "**checking battery state**" and it is not responding to any keys or anything. Can any one tell me how to solve it? I changed the CMOS battery but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is known bug that affects HP, Compaq, Dell and other manufactures. This is because of a change made in gnome-power-manager where by the estimate is done on time remaining, rather than percentage. This change does not play nice with some hardware and is why you are seeing (estimaing...) constantly.

The bug report about it is here if you fancy a read: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/629258

At this time, I believe there is no fix available. However you can click on the estimating... and it will bring up a more detailed view of your battery info, which will display the percentage of charge.

(this information may be [dated](https://askubuntu.com/a/7208/46312) somewhat should be relevant)

Answer (score -1):

try to change your bios settings, some graphic cards have windows specific bios settings. Disable the option in the bios. Mine name something like "optimus" or something