# Battery indicator is stuck at "Estimating" on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: indicator, battery

The title says it all. I took the battery out and then put it back. And, I tried using the machine without the battery. Nothing changed. I haven't found a solution. Does anyone have a idea about to fix this?

Comment: A bit more information of your system would be helpful.

Comment: Have you been looking at https://askubuntu.com/questions/7205/battery-indicator-is-stuck-on-estimating ?

Comment: give it a bit of time.

Comment: I've recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on 2 friend's notebook (Asus & Dell) and both of them have this problem. It's a very old bug which I don't think will be properly fixed anytime soon.

Comment: I checked the above link. I couldn't installed battery status applet. Unable to locate package battery-status, it says.  And  another ppa update in the below comment didn't work. I installed the cairo-dock but in the dock it says %0 battery charging and brand of the battery. I reinstalled and installed the (gnome-power-manager) package. Nothing changed. Also, This is my system info++

Comment: OS: Ubuntu 19.04 disco
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.0.0-17-generic
Uptime: 5m           
Packages: 2163                   
Shell: bash 5.0.3
 Resolution: 1366x768 
DE: GNOME 
WM: GNOME Shell
WM Theme: Adwaita
GTK Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3]
Icon Theme: Yaru
Font: Ubuntu 11        
CPU: Intel Core i5-2450M @ 4x 3.1GHz [60.0°C]                   
GPU: AMD TURKS (DRM 2.50.0 / 5.0.0-17-generic, LLVM 8.0.0)
RAM: 1303MiB / 7933MiB