# Battery stuck at 'Estimating...'

Tags: battery

Fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome version 3.36.2

[screenshoot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5kba.png)

[screenshoot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zu1W.png)

```
$upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

Output:

```
native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               TKBSS
  model:                NS2P3SZMC4WR
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              vie 29 may 2020 23:10:32 (36 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              0 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         88,8 Wh
    energy-full-design:  88,8 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    percentage:          0%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-charging-symbolic'
```

Thanks <3

Comment: This might be helpful https://askubuntu.com/questions/7205/battery-indicator-is-stuck-on-estimating