# Toshiba laptop Battery 0% and Acpi problems [NS2P3SZMC4WR]

Tags: power-management, battery, acpi

Most Toshiba laptops have had an issue with battery and power stuff since a long time ago. The issue has started since Ubuntu 16.04 until now. Now I am using Kubuntu 22.04. I tried Ubuntu generic official and xanmod and the official stable kernel [until 15.19.10], but all in vain.

- The battery always gets stuck at 0% particularly with laptops that have battery model NS2P3SZMC4WR.
- Sometimes device stuck at a black screen after return from sleep and the laptop hangs.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any error or flag which could lead me to the error in the logs.

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @Coda here is solution  for your problem
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245021/battery-stuck-at-estimating

Comment: This is not how things work on this site. It is a question and answer site you need to ask a question and then you can use the answer you own question feature to add your answer, Comments are used for others to ask you question about your question so they can get more info, not a place to have a conversation with yourself. A must read https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for advice.
I tried to improve all as I understood.
If there is anything else please tell me.
ok , I understood also about comments is only for question and improve it . [I won't write in it like this in the future , Thanks]

Answer (score 0):

I have few reputation so I can't tell others about solution in their questions, so I will post it here.

**Solution** : build kernel with this [PATCH](https://github.com/noobandnothing/Linux-patches/blob/acpi/0001-ACPI-Bypass-for-my-toshiba-power-issue.patch)

**Description** :
I tracked the issue ,I discovered that all was working  good until the
4.19.86 kernel.

So I checked [DIFF](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/diff?id=v4.19.86&id2=v4.19.85)
and After many tries maybe 50 or more.

I found the cause :
It was (**if statement was added in 4.19.86 COMMIT**) ,particularly checking if spaceid == 0 [ACPI_ADR_SPACE_SYSTEM_MEMORY] .

[Commit Link](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/diff/drivers/acpi/acpica/evregion.c?id=v4.19.86&id2=v4.19.85)

**Results** :

[Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQMIM.png)

[Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FxPt.png)

[Result Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cllCA.png)