# Device turns off when not plugged in?

Tags: power-management, battery

The Laptop only turns on when plugged in,
**always shows 0%** and turns off when I pull out the power plug. No matter how much time I charge, It always shows 0%.

It shows "Estimating..." instead of the battery level and I tried instructions from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/7205/1357034) to install a program to display the percentage but it didn't work due to 404 errors.
I don't think it would resolve the problem anyways because I think it is not just a matter of displaying the percentage. because when I run `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0`  it says: `percentage:          0%`.
It seems that the device thinks that the percentage is 0.

Maybe the driver is faulty?? I recently updated from 22.04 but the updation halted halfways and the software updater crashed.

---

Full info:

```
native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               PANASONIC
  model:                DELL 78V9D7C
  serial:               6845
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Thursday 08 June 2023 09:02:42 PM (18 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              0 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         30.2216 Wh
    energy-full-design:  41.44 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    voltage:             13.59 V
    charge-cycles:       N/A
    percentage:          0%
    capacity:            72.9286%
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-charging-symbolic'
```

**Update:** The battery is now behaving correctly. I DIDN'T do anything, I DIDN'T replace the battery. It resolved itself on its own. I am still curious what happened though.

**Update 2:** It became faulty again

**Important update:**  Recently I went to recovery mode and selected to fix broken files. now it got corrected again.

Comment: Your battery does not hold a charge. Replace it.

Comment: @waltinator Are you sure its a hardware problem? Maybe the driver is faulty?? I recently updated from 22.04 but the updation halted halfways and the software updater crashed.

Comment: I’m sure @waltinator is correct - the battery should charge irrespective of the os. Even with the laptop off, it should charge. It might not be the battery itself (eg could be the mobo or internal connections) but I’d bet this is hardware.

Comment: @Will I didn't replace the battery, but now it got resolved on its own and is  working perfectly. What do you think was the issue?

Comment: @waltinator I didn't replace the battery, but now it got resolved on its own and is working perfectly. What do you think was the issue?

Comment: The battery is not OS related. The OS probes the bios. If a battery does not charge it is likely dead but it could also be badly seated not making contact Maybe the latter was the issue and that corrected itself.

Comment: @Rinzwind Well, that explains it. But the battery is not visibly displaced; it is positioned correctly. And also, now it went back to showing zero again.

Comment: Recently I went to recovery mode and selected to fix broken files. now it got corrected again.